# Foreach template not rendering the second binding expression

Tags: knockout.js

I seem to have a misbehaving template. When I render

```
<span data-bind="text: CriteriaStub" />
```

in

```
<div class="row" data-bind="foreach: Foos" id=>         
            <span data-bind="text: CriteriaStub" />
            <button class="radius button small" data-bind="click: $parent.openEditDialogue($data)">Edit</button>
    </div>
```

I don't get the button rendered, but all the other bindings in the application work fine. When I comment out the span
I get errors regarding other unrelated bindings in the application.

Can you spot something here that is going on.

Comment: What is the correct error message what you get? Can you maybe put together a jsfiddle? You sample HTML is broken... e.g you have stuff like `id=>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you've hooked up the click event correctly. try:

```
click: $parent.openEditDialogue
```

$data is passed in as the first parameter to that method by [default](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html).

Comment: although I still don't understand why the second item didn't render, even this gets rendered once, ie just one p gets output ..:  <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>
            <p data-bind="text: CriteriaStub"></p>

Comment: I can only assume that as your code was assigning the *result* of a function call to the click event, it was just borking everything up.